# Does this pdf belong to any family of probability distributions?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I had to calculate a posterior distribution given the prior is $\operatorname{Gamma}(\alpha, \beta)$. At the end I got the posterior, as a function of $\theta$, is proportional to $\theta^a b^\theta$. All I know so far is that $a$ and $b$ are just some non-negative constants. Does this distribution belong to any sort of family? I guess this is analogous to some sort of gamma distribution. Also I guess we need to restrict on the value of $b$ for this posterior to be proper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may surprise you, but
$$
\theta^ab^\theta = \theta^{a}e^{-\theta\ln\frac1b} = \theta^{\alpha-1}e^{-\beta\theta},
$$
where $\alpha=a+1$ and $\beta=-\ln b$. Can you answer your own question now?